# On key press event not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a problem: I have a page with 2 sides, right side is RadGridView and on the left side I have filter with 2 controls one is textbox that called UserID and the other is searchbox so when I fill in the textbox like UserID: 7 and then I press enter it should find me the UserID on the grid.
I tried onkeypress event but it won't work.

This is my code:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
<telerik:RadButton ID="pSearchBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Style="display: block; width: 80px;" Font-Bold="False" ButtonType="SkinnedButton">
    <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbSearch" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your Telerik RadGrid into Update Panel ,

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="gridUpdatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadGrid .... your Grid's code
                                </telerik:RadGrid>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="pSearchBtn" EventName="Click" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

<telerik:RadButton ID="pSearchBtn" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Style="display: block; width: 80px;" Font-Bold="False" ButtonType="SkinnedButton">
    <Icon PrimaryIconCssClass="rbSearch" PrimaryIconLeft="4" PrimaryIconTop="4"></Icon>
</telerik:RadButton>
```

Note that , `ControlID` in `AsyncPostBackTrigger` must be your button's ID .